# Outer join in mongodb using $lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a **Channels** collection

```
{
  channel: "Xamper",  //unique
  subscribers: [
    ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002")
  ]
}
```

And a  **Users** collection

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
  name: "Bradman"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
  name: "Hartin"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
  name: "Migra"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
  name: "Polycor"
}
```

Now I need to find with **Channel** name `"Xamper"` and count the users which are not in `subscribers` array

So the output will be

```
{
  channel: "Xamper",
  unSubscribers: 1
}
```

Which is similar to the outer excluding join of SQL

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `$not` `$in` inside the lookup pipeline to get all the users document which are not present in subscribers array ?

Comment: Yes that's the answer... I just found...  Please post it as an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below pipeline in 3.6.

[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with pipeline to join the Channels collection to Users collection on subscribers

[`$count`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) with [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/not/) [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) to compare the subscribers against each id in the Users collection and output the no of matched documents.

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to project the output fields.

```
db.Channels.aggregate([
  { "$lookup":  {
    "from": "Users",
    "let": { "subscribers": "$subscribers" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$not": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$subscribers" ] }}}},
      { "$count": "count" }
    ],
    "as": "lookupresult"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "channel":  1,
    "unSubscribers": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$lookupresult.count", 0 ] }
  }}
])
```